# How to update MediaPlayerElement's buffer in realtime?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating Twitch player using MediaPlayerElement and I want to update MediaPlayerElement's buffer in real-time but I don't know how.

I tried to do it like this:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(64 * 1024 * 1024);
    BinaryWriter writer;
    BinaryReader reader;

    Task task;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    }

    async void ReadTask()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var bytes = reader.ReadBytes(1024 * 1024);

            if (bytes.Length == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            writer.Write(bytes);

            // Do some delay to see progress of loading
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I'm using file to speed up tests
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/output.ts"));

        reader = new BinaryReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync());

        // Write few first bytes
        writer.Write(reader.ReadBytes(1024 * 1024));

        // Start task which will write more bytes soon
        task = new Task(ReadTask);
        task.Start();

        StreamMediaPlayer.AreTransportControlsEnabled = true;
        StreamMediaPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
        StreamMediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.Volume = 0;
        StreamMediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(writer.BaseStream.AsRandomAccessStream(), "video/MP2T");
    }
}
```

This code works but player displays only first 1 MB which I wrote before setting source even if `TaskRead()` write more bytes while playing video.

I also tried to use method `CreateFromStreamReference` instead of `CreateFromStream` like this:

```cs
var s = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(writer.BaseStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
StreamMediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStreamReference(s, "video/MP2T");
```

But this don't work at all.

Here is full project with video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=175Z5HzK3MJ-Dm4ZX84r81lWYtZ0ahSSS

Comment: According to your description, you final target is to play the whole video. So, why not directly set source for `MediaPlayerElement` to play the whole video? For example, `<MediaPlayerElement Source="ms-appx:///Assets/output.ts" AutoPlay="True" />`

Comment: So, as I said in comment, I use file to speed up test. I forgot to mention that I get 2 seconds video every 2 seconds which I need to play in player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.
I have to use `MseStreamSource`.

First I need to create `MseStreamSource` with event like this:

```cs
streamSource = new MseStreamSource();
streamSource.Opened += (_, __) =>
{
    if (buffer is null)
    {
        // it will create buffer where I can write data
        buffer = streamSource.AddSourceBuffer("video/MP2T");
        buffer.Mode = MseAppendMode.Sequence;
    }
};
```

Then set the source:

```cs
StreamMediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromMseStreamSource(streamSource);
```

And if I want to add video I have to do it like this:

```cs
buffer.AppendBuffer(reader.ReadBytes(20 * 1024 * 1024).AsBuffer());
```

I have to make sure that buffer is not updating. This information provides `IsUpdating` property.